# Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Compatibility.VB6 Crashing VB.Net Application

Tags: vb.net

I came from VB6 and try to do a VB.net application on VB.net which can print .

I used

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Compatibility.VB6
```

And also installed the power pack. The application works fine on my Windows 8.1 but is crashing on Windows 7.
I tried to install the power pack on Windows 7 systems as well as I package and deployed on the windows 7 system but still no luck. Could anyone help me, why my application crashing on Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Problem in Signature :

Comment: Event Name: CLR20R3,

Comment: Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Sorted. My computer didn't have printer installed.

Comment: Hello Arman. For your information, you can answer to comment directly in your question in adding some sentence that explains your 4 last comments ! What means 'sorted' in your last comment ? sorted = resolved ?